# data table row details with select filter and export to Excel

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I want to add row details option with filtering and exporting to an Excel document. After adding export to program row details function are not working.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">


/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    var table_data_json = '[<?php for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){?>{"name":"Tiger Nixon","position":"System Architect","salary":"$320,800","start_date":"2011/04/25","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"5421"},<?php }?>{"name":"Garrett Winters","position":"Accountant","salary":"$170,750","start_date":"2011/07/25","office":"Tokyo","extn":"8422"},{"name":"Ashton Cox","position":"Junior Technical Author","salary":"$86,000","start_date":"2009/01/12","office":"San Francisco","extn":"1562"}]';

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "data": JSON.parse(table_data_json),
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [                       
                        {
                        "sExtends": "xls",
                        "sButtonText": "Export to Spreadsheet",
                        "mColumns": "visible",
                        "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                        "bFooter":false
                        }
                        ],
            "oSelectorOpts": {
                        "filter": "applied"
                        }

        },

        initComplete: function () {
              var r = $('#example tfoot tr');
              r.find('th').each(function(){
                $(this).css('padding', 8);
              });
              $('#example thead').append(r);
              $('#search_0').css('text-align', 'center');
            this.api().columns([1,7]).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );


    </script>
```

Comment: for export to excel use phpexcel.